# Finding all possible common substrings from a file consisting of strings using c++

Tags: c++, string, file

I am trying to find all possible common strings from a file consisting of strings of various lengths. Can anybody help  me out?

E.g input file is sorted:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC    
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG
AAAAAAAATTAGGCTGGG
AAAAAAAATTGAAACATCTATAGGTC
AAAAAAACTCTACCTCTCT
AAAAAAACTCTACCTCTCTATACTAATCTCCCTACA
```

and my desired output is:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC    
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG
AAAAAAAATTAGGCTGGG
AAAAAAAATTGAAACATCTATAGGTC
AAAAAAACTCTACCTCTCTATACTAATCTCCCTACA
```

[EDIT] Each line which is a substring of any other line should be removed.

Comment: Well, I was planning to downvote the question, but will only ask to elaborate a little more your question. Took me a while to understand your problem.

Comment: Are your input letters limited to A T C G ?

Comment: I don't understand why your desired output is what it is. The only common substring between all your inputs is "AAAAAAAA". Can you explain more?

Comment: And I still don't get it ;) @IanMedeiros it's DNA representation :)

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? should we write you a program? do you have absolutely no idea how to tackle this and want an algorithm? what did you try so far (if you tried anything)?

Comment: Looks like you want to discard all lines that are prefix of another line, correct?

Comment: Oh my god. Just lost about 30 mins of my day answering the wrong question. I'm downvoting this. Seriously!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically for each line, compare it with the next line to see if the next line is shorter or if the next line's substring is not equal to the current line. If this is true, the line is unique. This can be done with a single linear pass because the list is sorted: any entry which contains a substring of the entry will follow that entry.

A non-algorithmic optimization (micro-optimization) is to avoid the use of substr which creates a new string. We can simply compare the other string as though it was truncated without actually creating a truncated string.

```
vector<string> unique_lines;
for (unsigned int j=0; j < lines.size() - 2; ++j)
{
    const string& line = lines[j];
    const string& next_line = lines[j + 1];

    // If the line is not a substring of the next line,
    // add it to the list of unique lines.
    if (line.size() >= next_line.size() || 
        line != next_line.substr(0, line .size()))
        unique_lines.push_back(line);
}

// The last line is guaranteed to not be a substring of any
// previous line as the lines are sorted.
unique_lines.push_back(lines.back());

// The desired output will be contained in 'unique_lines'.
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to find substring and wanted to remove such string which is substring of any string.
For that you can use strstr method to find if a string is a substring of another string.
Hope this will help..

Comment: Well, I understood that him wants to remove any duplicated substring. Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: as Ashutosh said i am trying to remove such strings which are substring of any other string.thanks everybody

Comment: The question is tagged c++, as such std::string::find would be a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's probably not the fastest solution to solve your problem, but seems easy to implement. You just keep a histogram of chars that will represent a signature of a string. For each string that you read (separated for spaces), you count the numbers of each char and just stores it on your answer if there isn't any other string with the same numbers of each char. Let me illustrate it:

> aaa bbb aabb ab aaa

Here we have just two possible input letters, so, we just need an histogram of size 2.

- **aaa - hist[0] = 3, hist[1] = 0 : New one - add to the answer**
- bbb - hist[0] = 0, hist[1] = 3 : New one - add to the answer
- aabb - hist[0] = 2, hist[1] = 2 : New one - add to the answer
- ab - hist[0] = 1, hist[1] = 1 : New one - add to the answer
- **aaa - hist[0] = 3, hist[1] = 0 : Already exists! Don't add to the answer.**

  **The bottleneck of your implementation will be the histogram comparisons**, and there are a lot of possible implementations for it.

  The simplest one would be a simple linear search, iterating through all your previous answer and comparing with the current histogram, wich would be O(1) to store and O(n) to search. If you have a big file, it would take hours to finish.

  A faster one, but a lot more troublesome to implement, would use a hash table to store your answer, and use the histogram signature to generate the hash code. Would be to troublesome to explain this approach here.